# Input/Export data through MS Excel into OATS Scripts

Tags: excel, oracleapplications

When trying to get the Input the data from the Excel Sheet while working with OATS tool, it always gets into the catch block of the function. The below is the script written. Please help us resolve this issue.

```
public String getInputfromExcel(int argColumnNumber,int argRowNumber)throws Exception
    {
          String inputExcelName = dataPath+".xlsx";
          String cellContent = "12";
          try 
          {
                Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(inputExcelName));
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
                Cell a1 = sheet.getCell(argColumnNumber, argRowNumber);
                cellContent = (a1.getContents()).toString(); 
                System.out.println(cellContent.toString());
                workbook.close();
          }
          catch (Exception e) 
          {
            addReport("Getting Input From Excel", "Fail","Exception while reading value from excel sheet");

          }
          return cellContent;
     }
```

Comment: Put a `e.printStackTrace();` in the catch block. So you can see in stderr what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you Alex. However, when i see the console message it shows me the below error. Would you be able to help me debug this please. 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
      at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell(SheetImpl.java:356)
      at script.getInputfromExcel(script.java:196)
      at script.run(script.java:117)
      at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.api.IteratingVUser.run(IteratingVUser.java:350)
      at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.api.internal.IteratingAgent.run(IteratingAgent.java:799)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Comment: So how to interpret a stack trace: There is a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` `at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell(SheetImpl.java:356) at script.getInputfromExcel(script.java:196)`. The `getInputfromExcel` is your code. So which is line 196 there? I suspect `Cell a1 = sheet.getCell(argColumnNumber, argRowNumber);`. So getCell gets out of bounds. So what are the values of `argColumnNumber`and `argRowNumber` if the error occurs? Is the Cell(argColumnNumber, argRowNumber) really in the stored excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Axel has brought up the point. On a further note, if I remember correctly, the function sheet.getCell(arg1, arg2) has first argument as rowNumber and 2nd as columnNumber (both the values are 0 based index).

Answer (score 0):

Its old quetion....but just posting answer it might be helpful for someone needy.

In Oracle Application Testing Suite. NO NEED of external JARs  to read/write data.

You can enable DataTable module in the tool 
Complete explanation given here, http://www.testinghive.com/how-to-read-write-excel-in-oats/

```
//Define Sheet name to be read, and provide comma seperated to read multiple sheets
String sheetName = "Sheet1";
//Mention excel sheet path
String strFile= "C:\\Demo\\test.xls";

//Defined array list to add Sheets to read
List sheetList = new ArrayList();
sheetList.add(sheetName);
// Iports Sheet1
datatable.importSheets(strFile, sheetList, true, true);
//get rowcount
info("Total rows :"+datatable.getRowCount());
int rowcount=datatable.getRowCount();
//Loop to read all rows
for (int i=0;i<rowcount;i++)
{
//Set current row fromw here you need to start reading, in this case start from first row
datatable.setCurrentRow(sheetName, i);
String strCompany=(String) datatable.getValue(sheetName,i,"Company");
String strEmpFName=(String) datatable.getValue(sheetName,i,"FirstName");
String strEmpLName=(String) datatable.getValue(sheetName,i,"LastName");
String strEmpID=(String) datatable.getValue(sheetName,i,"EmpID");
String strLocation=(String) datatable.getValue(sheetName,i,"Location");

//prints first name and last name
System.out.println("First Name : "+strEmpFName+", Last Name : "+strEmpLName);

//Sets ACTIVE column in excel sheet to Y
String strActive="Y";
datatable.setValue(sheetName, i, datatable.getColumn(sheetName, datatable.getColumnIndex("Active")), strActive);

}

//Updates sheet with updated values ie ACTIVE column sets to Y
datatable.exportToExcel("C:\\Demo\\test1.xlsx");
```